# When replacing backslashes with Java regex, why does the Pattern class not recognize single backslashes?

Tags: java, regex

Specifically, when replacing some line

```
String hey = "\\t\\t";
```

to the line

```
String there = "\\\\t\\\\t";
```

one would think this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\");
Matcher m = p.matcher(hey);
if (m.find()) {
    m.replaceAll("\\\\");
}
```

would suffice to do the work, as the pattern `\\` returns a literal `\`, and given that the matcher finds it, the replacement `\\\\` should replace all/each with a literal `\\`.

However, the Pattern class doesn't understand that `\\` means to look for a backslash, and therefore throws an exception. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\` is also used as escape character within the regular expression. To match a single `\` you need a literal regular expression `\\` which must be specified as the Java string literal `"\\\\"`. Ugly, I know, but that's how it is.